# How to configure cache for ignite-spark-dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, ignite

I managed to save and load spark dataframe from ignite by the example here: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-data-frame

By following the code example when the cache is created in ignite it automatically has a name like "SQL_PUBLIC_name_of_table_in_spark".

One the other hand if I want to change some cache configuration I need to specify the same cache name in xml or code before creating ignite cache. Because cache configuration can not be changed after cache is created. See following code.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <!-- Set a cache name. -->
            <property name="name" value="SQL_PUBLIC_name_of_table_in_spark"/>
            <!-- Set cache mode. -->
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then one of them will be reject by "cache already exists" The result is I could't change any cache configuration by xml/code.

Is this expected? And how can I change the cache configuration in this case?

Comment: What do you need to change that can't be set using the `OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS ` option when creating the DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

The doc page you've link contains a code piece that creates an SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE person ( 
    id LONG,  
    name VARCHAR,  
    city_id LONG,  
    PRIMARY KEY (id, city_id) 
) WITH "backups=1, affinityKey=city_id”;
```

This SQL command is what actually creates the cache. You can change this command to change the parameters of the cache that will be created. Refer to the [`CREATE TABLE` doc](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table).

In particular, the parameter that gives the most flexibility is `WITH template=mytemplate`. It lets you create a cache from a pre-existing template configuration. To register a template you can specify it in your `cacheConfiguration` with a name ending with asterisk, like

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="mytemplate*"/>
            <!-- your parameters. -->
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can also specify the `WITH` parameters for `CREATE TABLE` in the `OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS` setting if the table is being created automatically by Spark.